# Generating a dynamic HTML table from django template language

Tags: django, python-3.x, html-table, django-templates

I am trying to generate a **dynamic html table** using **django template language** and i've not been able to do it yet.

Here is some info about my **Views.py** and **table.html**

**Views.py**

```
Class table(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'table.html'

      def get(self, request):
             header = {'header':['#', 'chemblID','Preferable Name']}
             rows = {'rows':{
                            'id':[1,2,3],
                            'chemblid':[534988,31290, 98765], 
                            'prefName':['A', 'B', 'C']}}

             return render(request,self.template_name, header,rows)
```

(The data is hard-coded since i am still testing. However it's supposed to change according to the user input.)

**table.html**

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for k in header %}
            <th>{{k}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for r in rows %}
            <tr>
                {% for e in r %}
                    <td>{{e.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.chemblid}}</td>
                    <td>{{e.prefName}}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to generate something like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     #      |      chemblID      |      Preferable Name      |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     1      |       534988       |            A              |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     2      |       31290        |            B              |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|     3      |       98765        |            C              |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|    ...     |        ...         |           ...             |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Thank you in advance for spending your time**

Comment: on the view you have to send the context as dict  in the render function. on the aboe example you are not doing that. that's why you are not able to get the variable values on template                    `render(request,self.template_name, context={'header':header,'rows':rows})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the get_context_data method to send context to your template

```
Class table(TemplateView):
      template_name = 'table.html'

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            ctx = super(table, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            ctx['header'] = ['#', 'chemblID','Preferable Name']
            ctx['rows'] = [{'id':1, 'chemblid':534988,'prefName':'A'},
                           {'id':2, 'chemblid':31290,'prefName':'B'},
                           {'id':3, 'chemblid':98765,'prefName':'C'}]
            return ctx
```

And you can remove the extra loop in the html

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            {% for k in header %}
            <th>{{k}}</th>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for r in rows %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{r.id}}</td>
                <td>{{r.chemblid}}</td>
                <td>{{r.prefName}}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

In template 
just change table class

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
```

In view

```
return render(request,self.template_name,{"header":header,"rows":rows})
```

Comment: by mistake i clicked submit, without giving full answer ....now updated

Comment: Still doesn't work.
with:
return render(request,self.template_name, header,rows)
I am able to do the header of table but not the rows.

With
return render(request,self.template_name, context ={"header": header,"rows":rows)
I just get a weird table like

First row with 1 column with text "Header" inside and a second row with 12 empty columns